# htaccess redirect doesn't work for zip.files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect auto-generated by CMS link to zip file to hosting. Redirect in my htaccess file looks approx like this(and doesn't work):

```
Redirect /files/generated.zip http://somehosting.com/something.zip
```

When I try something like this - it works:

```
Redirect /files/generated http://somehosting.com/something.zip
Redirect /files/generated.html http://somehosting.com/something.zip
```

Please, give me direction how to hack this.

By the way, this stuff worked OK before site was moved to other hosting (maybe here is deployed newer software that causes this weird behavior...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pro PHP dev and I don't want to go really deep to the problem. I tried Redirect and RewriteRule. Both of them perfectly work with most files but zip on my server. So, I decided to show users URLs without ".zip" extension and redirect from these short-handed links to the host-based file location:

```
Redirect /files/generated http://somehosting.com/something.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this way..

```
RewriteRule ^uplaod/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.+?\.(?:zip|7z|rar))$ /test.php?file=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, Malith. Can you please give me a hint where I should put my "/files/generated.zip" path in this regex? I need to configure redirect only for this specific file, not all zip files on the server.